# Google Code Jam 2013 R1B - Falling Diamonds

Tags: c#, algorithm

Yesterdays Code Jam had a question titled Falling Diamonds.  The full text can be found [here](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2434486/dashboard#s=p1), but in summary:

- Diamonds fall down the Y axis.
- If a diamond hits point to point with another diamond, there is a 50/50 chance it will slide to the right or left, provided it is not blocked from doing so.
- If a diamond is blocked from sliding one direction, it will always slide the other way.
- If a diamond is blocked in both directions, it will stop and rest on the blocking diamonds.
- If a diamond hits the ground, it will bury itself half way, then stop.
- The orientation of the diamond never changes, i.e. it will slide or sink, but not tumble.
- The objective is to find the probability that a diamond will rest at a given coordinate, assuming N diamonds fall.

The above requirements basically boil down to the diamonds building successively larger pyramids, one layer at a time.

Suffice to say, I have not been able to solve this problem to google’s satisfaction.  I get the sample from the problem description correct, but fail on the actual input files.  Ideally I would like to see a matched input and correct output file that I can play with to try and find my error.  Barring that, I would also welcome comments on my code.

In general, my approach is to find how many layers are needed to have one which contains the coordinate.  Once I know which layer I am looking at, I can determine a number of values relevant to the layer and point we are trying to reach.  Such as how many diamonds are in the pyramid when this layer is empty, how many diamonds can stack up on a side before the rest are forced the other way, how many have to slide in the same direction to reach the desired point, etc.

I then check to see if the number of diamonds dropping either makes it impossible to reach the point (probability 0), or guarantees we will cover the point (probability 1).  The challenge is in the middle ground where it is possible but not guaranteed.

For the middle ground, I first check to see if we are dropping enough to potentially fill a side and force remaining drops to slide in the opposite direction.  Reason being that in this condition we can guarantee that a certain number of diamonds will slide to each side, which reduces the number of drops we have to worry about, and resolves the problem of the probability changing when a side gets full.  Example: if 12 diamonds drop it is guaranteed that each side of the outer layer will have 2 or more diamonds in it, whether a given side has 2, 3, or 4 depends on the outcome of just 2 drops, not of all 6 that fall in this layer.

Once I know how many drops are relevant to success, and the number that have to break the same way in order to cover the point, I sum the probabilities that the requisite number, or more, will go the same way.

As I said, I can solve the sample in the problem description, but I am not getting the correct output for the input files.  Unfortunately I have not been able to find anything telling me what the correct output is so that I can compare it to what I am getting.  Here is my code (I have spent a fair amount of time since the contest ended trying to tune this for success and adding comments to keep from getting myself lost):

```
protected string Solve(string Line)
{
    string[] Inputs = Line.Split();
    int N = int.Parse(Inputs[0]);
    int X = int.Parse(Inputs[1]);
    int Y = int.Parse(Inputs[2]);

    int AbsX = X >= 0 ? X : -X;
    int SlideCount = AbsX + Y;  //number that have to stack up on one side of desired layer in order to force the remaining drops to slide the other way.
    int LayerCount = (SlideCount << 1) | 1; //Layer is full when both sides have reached slidecount, and one more drops
    int Layer = SlideCount >> 1; //Zero based Index of the layer is 1/2 the slide count
    int TotalLayerEmpty = ((Layer * Layer) << 1) - Layer; //Total number of drops required to fill the layer below the desired layer
    int LayerDrops = N - TotalLayerEmpty; //how many will drop in this layer
    int MinForTarget; //Min number that have to be in the layer to hit the target location, i.e. all fall to correct side
    int TargetCovered; //Min number that have to be in the layer to guarantee the target is covered
    if (AbsX == 0)
    {//if target X is 0 we need the layer to be full for coverage (top one would slide off until both sides were full)
        MinForTarget = TargetCovered = LayerCount;
    }
    else
    {
        MinForTarget = Y + 1; //Need Y + 1 to hit an altitude of Y
        TargetCovered = MinForTarget + SlideCount; //Min number that have to be in the layer to guarantee the target is covered
    }

    if (LayerDrops >= TargetCovered)
    {//if we have enough dropping to guarantee the target is covered, probability is 1
        return "1.0";
    }
    else if (LayerDrops < MinForTarget)
    {//if we do not have enough dropping to reach the target under any scenario, probability is 0
        return "0.0";
    }
    else
    {//We have enough dropping that reaching the target is possible, but not guaranteed

        int BalancedDrops = LayerDrops > SlideCount ? LayerDrops - SlideCount : 0; //guaranteed to have this many on each side
        int CriticalDrops = LayerDrops - (BalancedDrops << 1);//the number of drops relevant to the probablity of success
        int NumToSucceed = MinForTarget - BalancedDrops;//How many must break our way for success
        double SuccessProb = 0;//Probability that the number of diamonds sliding the same way is between NumToSucceed and CriticalDrops
        double ProbI;
        for (int I = NumToSucceed; I <= CriticalDrops; I++)
        {
            ProbI = Math.Pow(0.5, I); //Probability that I diamonds will slide the same way
            SuccessProb += ProbI;
        }

        return SuccessProb.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: You can download all the accepted solutions from the contest scoreboard. There's a "solution download" flag for that. Take one of them and compare the outputs.

Comment: I posted some of my ideas here... maybe it could help with some of the intuition needed to solve this problem...
http://bleedingedgemachine.blogspot.com/2013/05/2013-google-code-jam-round-1b.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general approach seems to fit the problem, though the calculation of the last probability is not completely correct.

Let me describe how I solved this. We are looking at pyramids. These pyramids can be assigned a layer, based on how many diamonds the pyramid has. A pyramid of layer `1` has only `1` diamond. A pyramid of layer `2` has `1 + 2 + 3` diamonds. A pyramid of layer `3` has `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5` diamonds. A pyramid of layer `n` has `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 2*n-1` diamonds, which equals `(2 * n - 1) * n`.

Given this, we can calculate the layer of the biggest pyramid we are able to build with a given number of diamonds:

```
layer = floor( ( sqrt( 1 + 8 * diamonds ) + 1 ) / 4 )
```

and the number of diamonds which are not needed in order to build this pyramid. These diamonds will start to fill the next bigger pyramid:

```
overflow = diamonds - layer * ( 2 * layer - 1 )
```

We can now see the following things:

- If the point is within the layer `layer`, it will be covered, so `p = 1.0`.
- If the point is not within the layer `layer + 1` (i.e. the next bigger pyramid), it will not be covered, so `p = 0.0`.
- If the point is within the the layer `layer + 1`, is might be covered, so `0 <= p <= 1`.

Since we only need to solve the last problem, we can simplify the problem statement a little bit: Given are the two sides of the triangle, `r` and `l`. Each side has a fixed capacity, the maximum number of diamonds it can take. What is the probability for one configuration `(nr, nl)`, where `nr` denotes the diamonds on the right side, `nl` denotes the diamonds on the left side and `nr + nl = overflow`.

This probability can be calculated using Bernoulli's Trails:

```
P( nr ) = binomial_coefficient( overflow, k ) * pow( 0.5, overflow )
```

However, this will fail in one case: If one side is completely filled with diamonds, the probabilities change. The probability, that the diamond falls on the completely filled side is now `0`, while the probability for the other side is `1`.

Assume the following case: Each side can take up to 4 diamonds, while 6 diamonds are still left. The interesting case is now `P( 2 )`, because in this case, the left side will take 4 diamonds.

Some examples how the 6 diamonds could fall down. `r` stands for the decision *go right*, while `l` stands for *go left*:

- `l r l r l l`  => For every diamond, the probability for each side was `0.5`. This case doesn't differ from the previous case. The probability for exactly this case is `pow( 0.5, 6 )`. There are 4 different cases like this (`rllllr`, `lrlllr`, `llrllr`, `lllrlr`). There are 10 different cases like this. The number of cases is the number of ways one element can be chosen from 5: `binomial_coefficient( 5, 2 ) = 10`
- `l r l l l r`  => The last diamond was going to fall on the right side, because the left side was full. The last probability was 1 for the right side and 0 for the left side. The probability for exactly this case is `pow( 0.5, 5 )`. There are 4 different cases like this: `binomial_coefficient( 4, 1 ) = 4`
- `l l l l r r`  => The last two diamonds were going to fall on the right side, because the left side was full. The last two probabilities were 1 for the right side and 0 for the left side. The probability for exactly this case is `pow( 0.5, 4 )`. There is exactly one case like this, because `binomial_coefficient( 3, 0 ) = 1`.

The general algorithm is to assume, that the last `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., nr` elements will go to the right side inevitably, then to calculate the probability for each of these cases (the last `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., nr` probabilites will be `1`) and multiply each probability with the number of different cases where the last `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., nr` probabilities are `1`.

See the following code. `p` will be the probability for the case that `nr` diamonds will go on the right side and the left side is full:

```
p = 0.0
for i in range( nr + 1 ):
    p += pow( 0.5, overflow - i ) * binomial_coefficient( overflow - i - 1, nr - i )
```

Now that we can calculate the probabilities for each individual combinations `(nr, nl)`, one can simply add all cases where `nr > k`, with k being the minimal number of diamonds for one side for which the required point is still covered.

See the complete python code I used for this problem: https://github.com/frececroka/codejam-2013-falling-diamonds/blob/master/app.py

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption are over simplicistic. You can download the correct answers of the large dataset caluclated with my solution:

http://pastebin.com/b6xVhp9U

You have to calc all the possible combinations of diamonds that will occupy your point of interests. To do that I have used this formula:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/382123/32707

You basically have to:

- Calc the height of the pyramid (ie calc the FIXED diamonds)
- Calc the number of the diamonds that can freely move on the left or on the right
- Calc the probability (with sums of binomial coeff)

With the latter and the Point Y you can apply that formula to calc the probability.

Also don't worry if you are not able solve this problem because it was pretty tough. If you want my solution in PHP here it is:

Note that you have to calc if the point is inside the fixed pyramid of is outside the fixed pyramid, also you have to do other minor checks.

```
<?php


set_time_limit(0);


$data = file('2bl.in',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);


$number = array_shift($data);

for( $i=0;$i<$number;$i++ ) {

    $firstLine = array_shift($data);
    $firstLine = explode(' ',$firstLine);


    $s = $firstLine[0];
    $x = $firstLine[1];
    $y = $firstLine[2];

    $s = calcCase( $s,$x,$y  );
    appendResult($i+1,$s);

}


function calcCase($s,$x,$y) {

    echo "S: [$s] P($x,$y)\n<br>";

    $realH = round(calcH($s),1);
    echo "RealHeight [$realH] ";

    $h = floor($realH);
    if (isEven($h))
        $h--;

    $exactDiamonds = progression($h);
    movableDiamonds($s,$h,$exactDiamonds,$movableDiamonds,$unfullyLevel);   


    $widthLevelPoint = $h-$y;


    $spacesX =  abs($x) - $widthLevelPoint;

    $isFull = (int)isFull($s,$exactDiamonds);



    echo "Diamonds: [$s], isFull [$isFull], Height: [$h], exactDiamonds [$exactDiamonds], movableDiamonds [$movableDiamonds], unfullyLevel [$unfullyLevel] <br> 
         widthlevel [$widthLevelPoint], 
         distance from pyramid (horizontal) [$spacesX]<br> ";


    if ($spacesX>1)
        return '0.0';

    $pointHeight = $y+1;


    if ($x==0 && $pointHeight > $h) {
        return '0.0';
    }


    if ($movableDiamonds==0) { 

        echo 'Fixed pyramid';

        if ( $y<=$h && abs($x) <= $widthLevelPoint )    
            return '1.0';
        else
            return '0.0';

    } 



    if ( !$isFull ) {

        echo "Pyramid Not Full ";


        if ($spacesX>0)
            return '0.0';


        if ($unfullyLevel == $widthLevelPoint)  
            return '0.5';


        else if ($unfullyLevel > $widthLevelPoint)
            return '0.0';


        else
            return '1.0';

    }


    echo "Pyramid full";


    if ($spacesX<=0)
        return '1.0';

    if ($movableDiamonds==0)
        return '0.0';




    if ( $movableDiamonds > ($h+1) ) {

        $otherDiamonds = $movableDiamonds - ($h+1);
        if ( $otherDiamonds - $pointHeight >= 0  ) {

            return '1.0';
        }


    }

    $totalWays = totalWays($movableDiamonds);
    $goodWays = goodWays($pointHeight,$movableDiamonds,$totalWays);

    echo "<br>GoodWays: [$goodWays], totalWays: [$totalWays]<br>";


    return sprintf("%1.7f",$goodWays / $totalWays);
}



function goodWays($pointHeight,$movableDiamonds,$totalWays) {


    echo "<br>Altezza punto [$pointHeight] ";

    if ($pointHeight>$movableDiamonds)
        return 0;


    if ( $pointHeight == $movableDiamonds )
        return 1;

    $good = sumsOfBinomial( $movableDiamonds, $pointHeight );

    return $good;
}

function totalWays($diamonds) {
    return pow(2,$diamonds);    
}


function sumsOfBinomial( $n, $k ) {

    $sum = 1;   //> Last element (n;n)
    for($i=$k;$i<($n);$i++) {

        $bc =  binomial_coeff($n,$i);
        //echo "<br>Binomial Coeff ($n;$i): [$bc] ";

        $sum += $bc;
    }

    return $sum;
}


// calculate binomial coefficient
function binomial_coeff($n, $k) {

  $j = $res = 1;

  if($k < 0 || $k > $n)
     return 0;
  if(($n - $k) < $k)
     $k = $n - $k;

  while($j <= $k) {
    $res = bcmul($res, $n--);
    $res = bcdiv($res, $j++);
  }

  return $res;

}

function isEven($n) {
    return !($n&1); 
}

function isFull($s,$exact) {
    return ($exact <= $s);
}

function movableDiamonds($s,$h,$exact,&$movableDiamonds,&$level) {

    $baseWidth = $h;
    $level=$baseWidth;

    //> Full pyramid
    if ( isFull($s,$exact) ) {
        $movableDiamonds = ( $s-$exact );
        return;
    }


    $movableDiamonds = $s;

    while( $level ) {

        //echo "<br> movable [$movableDiamonds] removing [$level] <br>" ;

        if ($level > $movableDiamonds)  
            break;

        $movableDiamonds = $movableDiamonds-$level;
        $level--;
        if ($movableDiamonds<=0)
            break;
    }

    return  $movableDiamonds;

}


function progression($n) {
    return (1/2 * $n *(1+$n) );
}

function calcH($s) {

    if ($s<=3)
        return 1;

    $sqrt = sqrt(1+(4*2*$s));
    //echo "Sqrt: [$sqrt] ";

    return ( $sqrt-1 ) / 2;
}





function appendResult($caseNumber,$string) {
    static $first = true;

    //> Cleaning file
    if ($first) {
        file_put_contents('result.out','');
        $first=false;
    }

    $to = "Case #{$caseNumber}: {$string}";
    file_put_contents( 'result.out' ,$to."\n",FILE_APPEND); 
    echo $to.'<br>';
}
```